# How to do this layout

Tags: css, materialize

I'm trying to do this layout, but confused. 
[image]
The images move out of the container and are aligned to the right edge (first row div/image) and left edge (second row div/image) respectively.
I'm using materializecss.. Appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

I apologize for leaving this off.. Here is the html part:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l5">
        <p>
            Action item goalposts i'll book a meeting so we can solution this before the sprint is over or organic growth low hanging fruit customer centric three-martini lunch. Organic growth into the weeds translating our vision of having a market leading platfrom and get six alpha pups in here for a focus group, or one-sheet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l6 offset-l1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/300" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l5">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/700/300" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 offset-l1">
        <p>
            Hit the ground running price point it's a simple lift and shift job. Clear blue water i’ve been doing some research this morning and we need to better, Q1 mobile friendly.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3">
        <p>
            Pull in ten extra bodies to help roll the tortoise downselect but we need to touch base off-line before we fire the new ux experience. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the css part just style for p etc. I am thinking and trying to do different methods.. nothing worked yet.

Comment: Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: How much are you confused ? you have done nothing and wish someone else to sort this out or have you tried things and fail at some points ? share what you have done so far, so you can get advise and help from SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good documentation on Materialize grid located: https://materializecss.com/grid.html.

Try doing something like this where you have 2 columns inside a container structure on two different rows.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">3-columns (one-fourth)</div>
  <div class="col s3">3-columns (one-fourth)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">3-columns (one-fourth)</div>
  <div class="col s3">3-columns (one-fourth)</div>
</div>
```

Edit: 
Add this style tag and the code in it in your head tags under the title:

```
    <style>
    .border-container {
        margin-top: 55px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    </style>
```

The margin top has pushed the div down so you can see the image and text. Also, I have added a border using the css border property.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I have added the html code above. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Add the style tags inside the head tags with the snippet in my answer. Run your code and see if that's going on the right track.

Comment: I am afraid not.. the images are within the container (border). Thank you..

Comment: It should be, as In the html it's within the grid.. I don't know how those images should be placed to get the look in the layout image above.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was to remove the `container` from the parent div and add it to the `<p>` tag because we want the properties of a container in our paragraph(content) only. After doing this, there was some extra `padding` in these `col` so added a class `.layout` and set `padding: 0 !important;`. A little bit of tweaking helped in making this layout, you can also tweak with the help of Chrome Dev Tool, use it, it's a great tool.

[image]

[Working Demo - Codepen](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/ZNgNzv)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l5 layout">
        <p class="container">
            Action item goalposts i'll book a meeting so we can solution this before the sprint is over or
            organic growth low hanging fruit customer centric three-martini lunch. Organic growth into the
            weeds translating our vision of having a market leading platfrom and get six alpha pups in here for
            a focus group, or one-sheet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l6 offset-l1 layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/300" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l5 layout">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/700/300" alt="" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 offset-l1 layout">
        <p>
            Hit the ground running price point it's a simple lift and shift job. Clear blue water i’ve been
            doing some research this morning and we need to better, Q1 mobile friendly.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 layout">
        <p class="container">
            Pull in ten extra bodies to help roll the tortoise downselect but we need to touch base off-line
            before we fire the new ux experience.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.layout{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```